# Class inheritance in PHP with Singleton Pattern only works if the instance variable in the inherited class is reinitialized. But why?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, singleton

I have a main class with the singleton function **instance()** and the associated variable **$instance**. Now I create several subclasses and let the main class inherit. I do not re-define the singleton function and variable, because of the useful inheritance. Unfortunately, each instance points to the 1st subclass. Only when in the subclasses the **$instance** variable is initialized to **null** it works, but why? With the keywords **static** and not **self**, the scope should remain in the subclass.

Here is the source code for a better understanding of what I mean:

```
// PHP Version 7.0
// Don't work as expected:

class base1
{
    /*
    * Instance of class
    * mixed
    */
    protected static $instance = null;

    /*
     * For Singleton Pattern
     */
    public static function instance() {

        if ( null == static::$instance ) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $test = "base1";
        var_dump($test);
    }
}

class sub11 extends base1
{
    public function test()
    {
        $test = "base1 -> sub11";
        var_dump($test);
    }
}

class sub12 extends base1
{
    public function test()
    {
        $test = "base1 -> sub12";
        var_dump($test);
    }
}

$sub11 = sub11::instance();
$sub12 = sub12::instance();
$sub11->test();
$sub12->test();
// Output:
// string(14) "base1 -> sub11"
// string(14) "base1 -> sub11"  // It's not different!!!

// Work as expected:

class sub21 extends base1
{

    /*
    * Instance of class
    * mixed
    */
    protected static $instance = null;  // Is needed, but why?

    public function test()
    {
        $test = "base1 -> sub21";
        var_dump($test);
    }
}

class sub22 extends base1
{
    /*
    * Instance of class
    * mixed
    */
    protected static $instance = null; // Is needed, but why?

    public function test()
    {
        $test = "base1 -> sub22";
        var_dump($test);
    }
}

$sub21 = sub21::instance();
$sub22 = sub22::instance();
$sub21->test();
$sub22->test();
// Output:
// string(14) "base1 -> sub21"
// string(14) "base1 -> sub22"  // This is correct !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first part it is working **correct** and as expected. Both classes **sub11** and **sub12** using **base1**'s field to store instance. So, the first one, which was instatiated, is placed there and preventing others to overwrite already created instance.

In second part, you specified personal static storage field for each descendant classes, so they uses not base class field, but own field instead (it overlaps parent field, as uses same name).

In a short, first pair of descendant classes uses `base1::$instance` to check and create instance. Second pair uses own fields, `sub21::$instance` and `sub22::$instance` for this task.

You can prevent this by discarding late static binding in *base1* class:

```
class base1
{
    /*
    * Instance of class
    * mixed
    */
    protected static $instance = null;

    /*
     * For Singleton Pattern
     */
    public static function instance() {
        if ( null == self::$instance ) {
        //           ^ self instead of static
            self::$instance = new static();
        //  ^ self instead of static
        }

        return self::$instance;
        //     ^ self instead of static
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $test = "base1";
        var_dump($test);
    }
}
```

I do really suggest you to read about [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) and difference between `self` and `static` keywords.

**UPDv1:**

If you still requiring to get only one instance of each descendant class, you can change singleton method to something like this:

```
class base1
{
    /*
    * Instances of descendant classes
    * array
    */
    protected static $instances = [];

    /*
     * For Singleton Pattern
     */
    public static function instance() {
        if (empty(self::$instances[static::class])) {
            $instance = new static();

            self::$instances[static::class] = $instance;
        } else {
            $instance = self::$instances[static::class];
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $test = "base1";
        var_dump($test);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the functions and variables of the basic class are inherited and are thus independent. For this, the keywords **static** (to remain in the inherited class) and **self** (to remain in the base class).

Comment: If I do your example my code don't work as expected: 1. Output: string(14) "base1 -> sub11", string(14) "base1 -> sub11". 2. Output: string(14) "base1 -> sub11", string(14) "base1 -> sub11"

Comment: @AndreasRex well, they are inherited and they are accessible, but not independent. You directly requiring to overlap them by own descendant class property with same name. In this case, as you using late static binding, the will look not into a parent field, but in it's own field. Read the link. I'm just clarifying for you how it behaves, so you could understand whats happening there.

Comment: @AndreasRex also, I've answered your `Is needed, but why?` question.

Comment: `self` references the called class using class name in the last non-forwarding call while `static` references the class its used in. This way each subclass accesses it's own `$instance` property not that of the parent class.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I understand static binding, but I'm not happy about how the **class extends** works. This is simply more work if you have to reinitialize variables in each subclass. Functions working correct, why not to variables when they are inherited? They are not inherited, as you can see, they remain in the basic class, if not redeclared in the subclass.

Comment: Oh wait! Now I got it! In the Baseclass the variable is defined static and therefore keeps in the baseclass!!! And that's why I must redeclare it in the subclass with static! Thanks a lot Guys!!! :)

Comment: @AndreasRex Updated

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! This is very good code. Thanks for the help and the explaining. I tested it and the results are correct, in both examples.

Comment: @AndreasRex if your issue is solved, you can accept answer. This would be helpful for other possible visitors in future. Cheers, glad to help.